# Blogger Post image Download option

Tags: blogger

How do allow my users to download an image which is uploaded in my blog post?

The right-click functionality is disabled on the page. So the user cannot download using right click.

I would like to create a link or button such as

```html
<a class="btnlink4" href="#">Download this Image.</a>
```

Usually, my blog posts have only one image.

Answer (score 1):

For images uploaded to Blogger itself, adding the query parameter **`?dl=1`** at the end of the image URL will cause them to be forcefully downloaded. Another way for doing this is, by suffixing `-d` after the sizing parameter in the image URL (aka `s1600`) For example -

```html
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-k1bwGQauV6I/WLyURMAuU9I/AAAAAAAAAD0/k_ZcX4sr_bENoB2P3P8MTEfN-ymfa3_ugCLcB/s1600/en_Contempo.jpg?dl=1">Download this Image.</a>

<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-k1bwGQauV6I/WLyURMAuU9I/AAAAAAAAAD0/k_ZcX4sr_bENoB2P3P8MTEfN-ymfa3_ugCLcB/s1600-d/en_Contempo.jpg">Download this Image.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `download` property of the `href` attribute of the `anchor` tag. It will download the image. First, when you upload an image, you get the link where it is uploaded something like this:

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GfBiEDZvfKo/W9iND3nZniI/AAAAAAAAASY/ZEo4RIBwDkQBOQsEPecPZJ9pBQDiqOdcgCPcBGAYYCw/s1600/Google%2BAdSense.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clear: right; float: right; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 1em;">
        <img border="0" data-original-height="161" data-original-width="293" height="174" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GfBiEDZvfKo/W9iND3nZniI/AAAAAAAAASY/ZEo4RIBwDkQBOQsEPecPZJ9pBQDiqOdcgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/Google%2BAdSense.jpg" width="320" />
    </a>
</div>
```

What you need to do is, add the word `download` at the end of an anchor tag with the image URL as it's `href` like this:

```
<a href="IMAGE-URL" download>Download Image</a>
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Sample here:

```
This is the image:
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GfBiEDZvfKo/W9iND3nZniI/AAAAAAAAASY/ZEo4RIBwDkQBOQsEPecPZJ9pBQDiqOdcgCPcBGAYYCw/s1600/Google%2BAdSense.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clear: right; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 1em;">
        <img height="174" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GfBiEDZvfKo/W9iND3nZniI/AAAAAAAAASY/ZEo4RIBwDkQBOQsEPecPZJ9pBQDiqOdcgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/Google%2BAdSense.jpg" width="320" />
    </a>
</div>

Download link
<a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GfBiEDZvfKo/W9iND3nZniI/AAAAAAAAASY/ZEo4RIBwDkQBOQsEPecPZJ9pBQDiqOdcgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/Google%2BAdSense.jpg" download>Click here to download it</a>
```